# Google API driveactivity.query gives insufficient scope error

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to use the node js snippet listed at https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/quickstart/nodejs to query the drive for changes.

```
const drive = google.drive("v2");
    console.log("oauth2Client is ", oauth2Client);
    const service = google.driveactivity({ version: "v2", auth: oauth2Client });

    const params = {
        pageSize: 10,
        consolidationStrategy: { legacy: {} },
        // filter: `time > '2021-03-01T00:00:00Z' and time < '2021-03-31T00:00:00Z' and ` +
        itemName: `items/${thirdPartyId}`,
    };
    const queryRes = await service.activity.query({
        requestBody: params,
        auth: oauth2Client,
    });
    console.log("queryRes is ", queryRes);
```

However, I'm getting insufficient authentication scopes error that looks like the following.

```
data: {
      error: {
        code: 403,
        message: 'Request had insufficient authentication scopes.',
        errors: [
          {
            message: 'Insufficient Permission',
            domain: 'global',
            reason: 'insufficientPermissions'
          }
        ],
        status: 'PERMISSION_DENIED',
        details: [
          {
            '@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo',
            reason: 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT',
            domain: 'googleapis.com',
            metadata: [Object]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    headers: {
      'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000',
      'cache-control': 'private',
      connection: 'close',
      'content-encoding': 'gzip',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      date: 'Sat, 25 Feb 2023 23:37:48 GMT',
      server: 'ESF',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      vary: 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer',
      'www-authenticate': 'Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error="insufficient_scope", scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity.readonly"',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'x-xss-protection': '0'
    },
```

It is telling me I need one of the two scopes from "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity.readonly"](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity.readonly%22).
I printed my Oauth scope shown here

```
scope: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/docs',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity.readonly'
    ],
```

and it apparently has both of these scopes already. I'm wondering if anyone has any idea to bypass the error.

Comment: Please add your code and output to your question

Comment: I think that from `Request had insufficient authentication scopes.`, in this case, it is required to confirm the current scopes of your access token. When I saw your script and scopes, it seems that you want to use "Method: activity.query" of Drive Activity API. In your scope, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity` is included. So, I think that your script works when the access token has the scopes. From your current issue, in this case, how about reauthorizing the scopes? But, I cannot know your whole script. So, I'm not sure about your detailed script. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike Would it be possible that v3 and v2 access tokens are different? I'm using the v3 tokens but the APi is v2

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Would it be possible that v3 and v2 access tokens are different? I'm using the v3 tokens but the APi is v2`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks so much for getting back! So this activity.query API is an API that uses the "v2" google drive API. However, the Oauth I'm using saves the user's "v3" access token". Would the "v3" access token and the "v2" access token be different for the same user?

Comment: Have you tried logging out the user and authorizing it again. I also had the same issue as yours but I have the scopes updated, the only thing I forgot is to re-authorize the accessToken on the current session.